# Unable to process big numbers

Tags: java

```
import java.io.;
import java.util.;
import java.math.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a=sc.nextInt();
        int b=sc.nextInt();
        BigInteger bi1=new BigInteger(String.valueOf(a));
        BigInteger bi2=new BigInteger(String.valueOf(b));
        BigInteger biadd=bi1.add(bi2);
        BigInteger bimultiply=bi1.multiply(bi2);
        System.out.println(biadd);
        System.out.println(bimultiply);
    }
}
```

Taking small numbers gets add and multiplied easily but while running this code for big numbers it shows **Runtime error**

Comment: What error does it give you

Comment: Why are you using `sc.nextInt` here if you want to work with large numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code Take BigInteger as input not Int.

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.util.*;
   import java.math.*;

 public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    BigInteger a = sc.nextBigInteger();
    BigInteger b = sc.nextBigInteger();

    BigInteger bi1=new BigInteger(String.valueOf(a));
    BigInteger bi2=new BigInteger(String.valueOf(b));
    BigInteger biadd=bi1.add(bi2);
    BigInteger bimultiply=bi1.multiply(bi2);
    System.out.println(biadd);
    System.out.println(bimultiply);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String a = sc.next();

        String b = sc.next();

        BigInteger bi1 = new BigInteger(a);

        BigInteger bi2 = new BigInteger(b);
        BigInteger biadd = bi1.add(bi2);
        BigInteger bimultiply = bi1.multiply(bi2);
        System.out.println(biadd);
        System.out.println(bimultiply);
    }
}
```

because `nextInt()` expects something in range [-2^31, 2^31-1], already trying to convert the strings you enter in your console into ints.

What you want to do is read your input into a string and convert that string into a `BigInteger`.

Comment: sir you are taking strings as input but i have to take numbers as input.....

Comment: @NikhilBansal numbers are strings in alphabet A={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}. What is the problem? In the code you posted you also take strings as input, and the nextInt method converts those strings into ints.

Comment: Sorry sir , I was little confused but now its clear.....

Answer (score 0):

When you try to get big number by `int a=sc.nextInt()`, it might be too big for `int`.

You can change it to this:

```
String a = sc.nextLine();
String b = sc.nextLine();
BigInteger bi1 = new BigInteger(a);
BigInteger bi2 = new BigInteger(b);
```

And, you should use

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
```

Comment: Yess sir you are right that i should not use int but you are using string datatype which will take string as input but i want numbers as input.